# curl in a bash script with error curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Tags: curl

i have the script below

```
echo Getting Data from MyTotalControl Website
/etc/openhab2/scripts/therm.py -s > /var/log/honeywell.log
TEMPDATA="/var/log/honeywell.log"
#
#
echo Checking Indoor Temp
TEMPSTATUS=$( grep "Indoor Temperature" "$TEMPDATA" | sed -n -e 's/^.*Indoor Temperature: //p')
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "$TEMPSTATUS" "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/rest/items/IndTemp" "\n"
echo "$TEMPSTATUS"
#
#
exit 0
```

i get the error:

```
Getting Data from MyTotalControl Website
Checking Indoor Temp
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
28
: numeric argument required: line 39: exit: 0
```

it fetches the indoor temp but i have a curl error and that numeric argument.

when i use the curl command in terminal

```
$ curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "33" "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/rest/items/IndTemp"
```

it works as expected and updates my item.
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks you in advance.

Comment: what exactly is that final newline in you script after the URL supposed to do? I guess that's your problem...

Comment: Tried without "\n" but the same problem.